# What could cause a blank sc-status in the IIS log?

Tags: iis, http, log-files

I'm troubleshooting a problem reported by customers where they're getting a white screen from our ASP.NET MVC application. It's a group of schools in a single school district in one city. No other users are reporting the problem, and even within that district, many of the requests do succeed.

I know their IP block, so I've looked at the IIS log records within that block. I am seeing tens of thousands of requests where the `sc-status` is simply blank. Outside of that IP block, this never happens. So I think the no-status requests are causing the white screen.

So far, the only other pattern I can see is that the failed requests are generally from a small family of browsers:

```
Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_10_2)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML
```

There are many variants of this, but they seem to be mostly on Mozilla 5 on Apple based browsers.

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an Excel glitch: the codes were there, but whenever the user agent string contained a comma, Excel was truncating the line there, even when requested NOT to use a comma as a delimiter.

So it was not a data problem, but a problem viewing that data.